# Counting class frequencies to balance classes in tensorflow

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I am working on my own implementation of wavenet in tensorflow.  I keep having this issue where the audio goes to zero when generating.  I think that it might help if my classes were weighted correctly.  To do this I decided to divide my cost function by the frequency in which its value occurs.  Right now I am keeping a running total of the frequencies as I train.  To compute them I unroll the list of 128 different distinct values and I compute the count for each one.  I feel like there should be a way to do this with vector operations but I am unsure how.  Do any of you know how I can do away with the for loop?

```
with tf.variable_scope('training'):
    self.global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', [], tf.int64, initializer = tf.constant_initializer(), trainable = False)
    class_count = tf.get_variable('class_count', (quantization_channels,), tf.int64, initializer = tf.constant_initializer(), trainable = False)
    total_count = tf.get_variable('total_count', [], tf.int64, initializer = tf.constant_initializer(), trainable = False)

    y_ = tf.reshape(y_, (-1,))
    y = tf.reshape(y, (-1, quantization_channels))

    counts = [0] * quantization_channels
    for i in range(quantization_channels):
        counts[i] = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(y_, i), tf.int64))

    counts = class_count + tf.pack(counts)
    total = total_count + tf.reduce_prod(tf.shape(y_, out_type = tf.int64))
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(class_count, counts), tf.assign(total_count, total)]):
        class_freq = tf.cast(counts, tf.float32) / tf.cast(total, tf.float32)

    weights = tf.gather(class_freq, y_)
    self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_) / (quantization_channels * weights + 1e-2))
    self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), y_), tf.float32))

    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
    grads = opt.compute_gradients(self.cost)
    grads = [(tf.clip_by_value(g, -1.0, 1.0), v) for g, v in grads]
    self.train_step = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step = self.global_step)
```

Comment: One idea: you could write something like this: `tf.unsorted_segment_sum(tf.ones([...]), y_)` in place of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `tf.histogram_fixed_width` function to get a distribution of class labels per batch.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.histogram_fixed_width.md